# Is this answer sufficient to prove? The question is related to second partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

Is this answer sufficient to prove ? Does there exist a notation mistake or else?

### Problem

> Suppose that the functions $\varphi: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $\psi: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ have continuous second partial derivatives.
>
> Define $f(x,y) = \varphi(x-y) + \psi (x + y), \quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2.$
>
> Prove that 
>   $$
> \frac {\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} - \frac {\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = 0, \quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2.
> $$

### Solution

\begin{align}
\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} &= \varphi'(x-y) + \psi'(x+y) \\
\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} &= \frac \partial{\partial x} \left( \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} \right ) = \varphi''(x-y) + \psi''(x+y)\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} &= -\varphi'(x-y) + \psi'(x+y) \\
\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} &= \frac \partial{\partial y} \left( \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} \right ) = \varphi''(x-y) + \psi''(x+y)
\end{align}
Then
$$
\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - \frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = \varphi''(x-y) + \psi''(x+y) - \left [ \varphi''(x-y) + \psi''(x+y)\right ] = 0\quad \blacksquare
$$

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Really? Thank you for feedback :) @Tunococ

Comment: Ok. I take it back. There are three typos. On the first line, it's supposed to be $\psi'(x + y)$, on the second line, it's supposed to be $\psi''(x + y)$, and on the last line, it's supposed to be $\psi''(x + y)$ in both places.

Comment: Ohh so sorry while I focused on only solveing this, I didnt pay attention the signs. All of them are the form $(x+y)$ thank you for attention @Tunococ

Comment: I editted. Thanks:) @tunococ

Comment: @B11b: _I edited_... w00t? oO

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but, What means "woot?"? @Kaster

Comment: @B11bKaster mispelled. He meant [w$00$t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W00t).

Comment: Okay thanks. I learnt its meaning. I know only academic language. I dont have sufficient spoken language @GitGud

Comment: By the way, on MSE websites,I have ever seen that you are the best person. You seem sincere and helpful. @GitGud

Comment: @B11b Thank you for the kind words.